# jQuery Mobile Randomly Display Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, mobile, random, checkbox

Im creating a Survey by phone, but options have to be displayed randomly

For example:

Favorite color:

```
[ ] RED
[ ] BLUE
[ ] YELLOW
```

Another case:

```
[ ] BLUE
[ ] YELLOW
[ ] RED
```

Yet another:

```
[ ] YELLOW
[ ] BLUE
[ ] RED
```

Etc....

Has anybody done random checkboxes using JQM?

I programmed this function and it works fine on the Web, but it does not work using JQM ie.  `<fieldset data-role='controlgroup'>`

This is my markup:

```
<fieldset data-role='controlgroup'>        
<input id ='C_1'type='checkbox' name='C_[]' value='1'><label for='C_1'>RED</label>
<input id ='C_2'type='checkbox' name='C_[]' value='2'><label for='C_2'>BLUE</label>
<input id ='C_3'type='checkbox' name='C_[]' value='3'><label for='C_3'>YELLOW</label>
</fieldset>
```

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//1. Cheate array of checkboxes HTML

var HtmCheck = new Array();

//2. Save HTML code into array    

HtmCheck[0]= $('#C_1').html();
HtmCheck[1]= $('#C_2').html();
HtmCheck[2]= $('#C_3').html();
HtmCheck[3]= $('#C_4').html();
HtmCheck[4]= $('#C_5').html();

//3. Sort array randomly, this func is tested and works fine!


for(var j, x, i = HtmCheck.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = HtmCheck[--i], HtmCheck[i] = HtmCheck[j], HtmCheck[j] = x);


//4 Reasign sorted HTML

$('#C_1').html(HtmCheck[0]);        
$('#C_2').html(HtmCheck[1]);        
$('#C_3').html(HtmCheck[2]);        
$('#C_4').html(HtmCheck[3]);        
$('#C_5').html(HtmCheck[4]);

//5 Refresh checks

$("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio('refresh');


});
```

Comment: Ok, you've posted a yelling question with broken formatting. But why do you use UPPER_CASE in your code comments?

Comment: http://img.clubic.com/05271200-photo-caps-lock.jpg

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: So... is stackoverflow becoming  place where new users are not welcomed? I get it, he used caps, get over it, leave A comment. I understand that most of you were born with the keyboard in your hands and the know-how of the internet imprinted in you brain but there are some people that are different. Is it something wrong with how the question was asked? Do you know what's wrong? Then edit it...

Comment: How is this "not a real question"?!

Comment: @ChrisGhenea I downvoted the question for poor formatting and then removed my downvote when he improved it. I also upvoted the comment "-1 for yelling.". It explained the exact reason I downvoted, so no reason to be redundant. This is a perfectly acceptable reason to downvote: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>It's hard to answer without seeing your markup</s> *(now that you've posted your markup, see update at the bottom)*, but let's assume you've used `label` elements around the checkboxes and they're all in a container (here I'll use a `fieldset` with `data-role="controlgroup"` as you've mentioned that in the comments):

```
<fieldset id="checkboxes" data-role="controlgroup">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="red">Red</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="blue">Blue</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="yellow">Yellow</label>
</fieldset>
```

This will put them in semi-random order *(edit: see note below, now that you've posted your markup, it's slightly different to mine)*:

```
var container = $("#checkboxes");
var cbs = container.children("label");
var index;
for (index = 0; index < cbs.length; ++index) {
    $(cbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * cbs.length)]).appendTo(container);
}
```

Complete example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/epituz/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/epituz/2/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Semi-Random Checkboxes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <fieldset id="checkboxes" data-role="controlgroup">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="red">Red</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="blue">Blue</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="yellow">Yellow</label>
  </fieldset>

  <script>
    (function($) {
      var container = $("#checkboxes");
      var cbs = container.children("label");
      var index;
      for (index = 0; index < cbs.length; ++index) {
          $(cbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * cbs.length)]).appendTo(container);
      }
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Edit**: Now that you've posted your markup, I see you're using `id` and `for` to relate the `input` and `label` elements, rather than containment. Containment works great on desktop browsers other than IE6, but just in case you know something I don't about mobile support of it, then:

```
<fieldset id="checkboxes" data-role="controlgroup">
<input id="C_1" type="checkbox" value="red"><label for="C_1">Red</label>
<input id="C_2" type="checkbox" value="blue"><label for="C_2">Blue</label>
<input id="C_3" type="checkbox" value="yellow"><label for="C_3">Yellow</label>
</fieldset>
```

and

```
var container = $("#checkboxes");
var cbs = container.children("input");
var index;
var entry;
for (index = 0; index < cbs.length; ++index) {
    entry = $(cbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * cbs.length)]);
    entry.add(entry.next()).appendTo(container);
}
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/epituz/3) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/epituz/3/edit)

Comment: Thanks pal, I alreaded sbmitted the markup

Comment: YES, YOUR DEMO WORKS FINE, BECAUSE YOU ARE NOT USING JQM, JUST PLAIN JQUERY, TRY YOUR CODE USING <fieldset data-role='controlgroup'>  AND YOU'LL GET IT

Comment: Sorry for the Upper case, I forgot the rule of Yelling :(

Comment: @AbrahamPetit: I don't believe there's anything about jQuery Mobile that would change the above. *Edit*: And indeed, there isn't, I've put a new demo in the answer using jQuery Mobile and a `fieldset data-type="controlgroup"`.

Comment: @AbrahamPetit: (Now that you've posted the markup.) The only real difference in our markup is that you're using `id` and `for` rather than containment to relate the `input` and `label` elements. Containment is better when possible (and supported by all modern browsers and several old ones as well), but just in case you know something about mobile support I don't, I've shown how to do it your way, too.

Comment: YEs! you got the points!